# How to join two tables with ssp.class.php

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

I started using [DataTables Table plug-in for jQuery](http://datatables.net) and got some problems. I am using example code from [here](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html).

I have MySQL table witch looks like that:

> id | name | father_id

`father_id` is `id` value in same table only in different row. So if I want to know father name i have to search in same table `WHERE id = father_id`. But what DataTable does it just show the contents of MySQL table as it is.

In my DataTable i want to show data like that:

> id | name | father_name | father_id

So when DataTable takes data from MySQL table, but before it creates table I want to change column value which at that time is value of `father_id` in the same row in MySQL. I want too add `father_name` by searching for it with particular `father_id`.

Comment: how about handling the issue rdbms side? is an option for you to add that field in the source? it would be quicker and more effective to alter the source query with a self join on the source table.

Comment: DataTables itself is agnostic in terms of this problem. Everything that needs solving is leading up to the dataset being returned to the browser.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As [PaulF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31005385/3549014) pointed out, you need to use `JOIN` or sub-query to retrieve father's name from the same table.

I assume you're using `ssp.class.php` to process your data on the server-side based on the example you've mentioned.

Class `ssp.class.php` doesn't support joins and sub-queries, but there is a workaround. The trick is to use sub-query as shown below in `$table` definition. Replace `table` with your actual table name in the sub-query.

```
$table = <<<EOT
 (
    SELECT 
      a.id, 
      a.name, 
      a.father_id, 
      b.name AS father_name
    FROM table a
    LEFT JOIN table b ON a.father_id = b.id
 ) temp
EOT;

$primaryKey = 'id';

$columns = array(
   array( 'db' => 'id',          'dt' => 0 ),
   array( 'db' => 'name',        'dt' => 1 ),
   array( 'db' => 'father_id',   'dt' => 2 ),
   array( 'db' => 'father_name', 'dt' => 3 )
);

$sql_details = array(
   'user' => '',
   'pass' => '',
   'db'   => '',
   'host' => ''
);

require 'ssp.class.php';
echo json_encode(
   SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
```

You also need to edit `ssp.class.php` and replace all instances of `` FROM `$table` ``  with `FROM $table`  to remove backticks.

Make sure all column names are unique otherwise use `AS` to assign an alias.

#### NOTES

There is also [github.com/emran/ssp](https://github.com/emran/ssp) repository that contains enhanced `ssp.class.php` supporting JOINs.

#### LINKS

See [jQuery DataTables: Using WHERE, JOIN and GROUP BY with ssp.class.php](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-using-where-join-and-group-by-with-ssp-class-php/) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for very nice informative answer. But I occured a problem. Now it tells me 

'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1059 Identifier name is too long'

Comment: @hockeyman, you're right, you also need to edit `ssp.class.php` and replace all instances of ``FROM `$table` `` with ``FROM $table `` to remove backticks. I have updated my answer and also added repository containing enhanced `ssp.class.php`.

Comment: Now if `father_id` has no value it doesnt show the row. How can I make so that if there is no `father_id` show the row only leave field with `father_name` empty?

Comment: @hockeyman, there was minor issue with SQL which I fixed however it should return a record even when `father_name` isn't found. Maybe DataTables complains about fields with `null` values in JSON, try putting `(CASE WHEN b.name IS NOT NULL THEN b.name ELSE '' END) AS father_name` instead of `b.name AS father_name` and see if that helps.

Comment: great (Y)           Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Recently I found myself using DataTables and requiring a more complex JOIN and WHERE clause that the original ssp.class.php did not support. So I modified the original file and changed the API a tiny bit to provide a table that gave me the flexibility I needed. I combined the functionality of the "SSP::simple" and "SSP::complex" into a single function named "SSP::process".

Due to the length of the script, I put it on pastebin.com here: [ssp.class.php](http://pastebin.com/B8ZG9NQs)

And a quick example of how I use it:

```
private function get_recent_payments() {
    global 
        $pdoHost, $pdoUser, 
        $pdoPass, $pdoDatabase;

    // SQL server connection information
    $sql_details = array(
        'user' => $pdoUser,
        'pass' => $pdoPass,
        'db'   => $pdoDatabase,
        'host' => $pdoHost
    );

    // DataTables server-side processing
    require_once('ssp.class.php');

    $options = [
        'table' => 'payments',
        'alias' => 'l',
        'primaryKey' => 'id',
        'columns' => [
            [ 'db' => 'id',       'dt' => 0 ],
            [
                'db' => 'client_id',     
                'dt' => 1,
                'join' => [
                    'table' => 'clients',
                    'on' => 'id',
                    'select' => 'first_name',
                    'alias' => 'c',
                    'as' => 'fname',
                ]
            ],
            [
                'db' => 'client_id',     
                'dt' => 2,
                'join' => [
                    'table' => 'clients',
                    'on' => 'id',
                    'select' => 'last_name',
                    'alias' => 'c'
                ]
            ],
            [ 'db' => 'pay_date', 'dt' => 3 ]
        ],
        'where' => [
            [
                'db' => 'client_id',
                'op' => '!=',
                'value' => $_SESSION['client_id']
            ]
        ]
    ];

    $this->response(SSP::process($_REQUEST, $sql_details, $options));
}
```

The 'where' and 'whereResult' (SEE 'SSP::complex' for Details) clauses of the options array may also have an 'alias' to refer to a column in a joined table.

Example SQL Query passed to the server:

```
SELECT l.`id`, c.`first_name` AS 'fname', c.`last_name`, l.`pay_date` 
        FROM `payments` l
        JOIN `clients` c ON (c.`id` = l.`client_id`)
        WHERE l.`client_id` != :binding_0
        ORDER BY l.`pay_date` DESC
        LIMIT 0, 5
```

I took the structured array route because this enabled me to build the queries while maintaining the rigidity of queries with backticks and bound statement parameters. I'm putting up this post in hopes that others will find it as useful as I have.