# Complex MySQL query : solution to work with views (datatables...)

Tags: php, mysql, datatables, subquery

I need to use a complex query with joins, sub queries etc in a php script to generate a Json for a datatable server side process. 
Datatables does not accept sub queries, so I need a "flat" query . I thought of generating a view but subqueries are not accepted either on MySQL views!
Here is the MySQL query. What would you recommend ?

```
SELECT a.Customers
    ,a.Agent
    ,a.status_name AS Current_Status
    ,round(c.LTGGR - e.LT_TotBonus, 0) AS LT_NGR
    ,CONCAT (
        round(e.LT_TotBonus / c.LTRM * 100, 0)
        ,'%'
        ) AS LT_Bonus_RM_per
    ,CONCAT (
        'x'
        ,round(c.LTBETS / (c.LTRM + e.LT_TotBonus), 0)
        ) AS LT_Wagering
    ,coalesce(d.Last_30D_RM, 0) AS Last_30D_RM
    ,coalesce(d.Last_30D_NGR, 0) AS Last_30D_NGR
    ,coalesce(g.CashBack_Last30D, 0) AS Cash_Back_30D
    ,CONCAT (
        (f.cash_back_BO_per * 100)
        ,'%'
        ) AS status_cash_Back_BO_per
    ,CONCAT (
        f.cash_back_per * 100
        ,'%'
        ) AS cash_back_percent
    ,CASE 
        WHEN f.cash_back_per = 0
            THEN 0
        WHEN c.LTGGR - e.LT_TotBonus < 0
            THEN 0
        WHEN d.Last_30D_RM < 0
            THEN 0
        WHEN e.LT_TotBonus / c.LTRM * 100 >= f.cash_back_BO_per * 100
            THEN 0
        WHEN round(d.Last_30D_NGR * f.cash_back_per, 0) - coalesce(g.CashBack_Last30D, 0) < 0
            THEN 0
        WHEN isnull(d.Last_30D_NGR)
            THEN 0
        WHEN d.Last_30D_NGR < 0
            THEN 0
        ELSE round(d.Last_30D_NGR * f.cash_back_per, 0)
        END AS cash_back_calc
    ,CASE 
        WHEN f.cash_back_per = 0
            THEN 'No Cash Back for Status'
        WHEN c.LTGGR - e.LT_TotBonus < 0
            THEN 'LT NGR <0'
        WHEN d.Last_30D_RM < 0
            THEN 'No RM Deposit in 30D'
        WHEN e.LT_TotBonus / c.LTRM * 100 >= f.cash_back_BO_per * 100
            THEN 'Above LT Bonus Percentage'
        WHEN coalesce(g.CashBack_Last30D, 0) > 0
            AND round(d.Last_30D_NGR * f.cash_back_per, 0) - coalesce(g.CashBack_Last30D, 0) < 0
            THEN 'CashBack in 30D> Cash Back Calculated'
        WHEN isnull(d.Last_30D_NGR)
            THEN 'No NGR in 30D'
        WHEN d.Last_30D_NGR < 0
            THEN 'Negative NGR in 30D'
        ELSE ''
        END AS note
FROM (
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM players_levels
        WHERE date_format(Date_Status, '%Y-%m') = (
                SELECT date_format(max(players_levels.Date_Status), '%Y-%m')
                FROM players_levels
                )
        GROUP BY Customers
        ) a LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT *
        FROM players_levels
        WHERE date_format(Date_Status, '%Y-%m') = (
                SELECT date_format(max(players_levels.Date_Status) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m')
                FROM players_levels
                )
        ) b ON a.Customers = b.Customers
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT Customers
            ,sum(Total_Win_Loss) AS LTGGR
            ,sum(Real_Money) AS LTRM
            ,sum(Total_Bets) AS LTBETS
        FROM Online_customer_activity_v2
        GROUP BY Customers
        ) c ON a.Customers = c.Customers
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT Customers
            ,sum(Real_Money) AS Last_30D_RM
            ,sum(Total_Win_Loss) - sum(_Bonuses) AS Last_30D_NGR
        FROM Online_customer_activity_v2
        WHERE Online_customer_activity_v2.DATE >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
        GROUP BY Customers
        ) d ON a.Customers = d.Customers
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT Account
            ,sum(CASE 
                    WHEN Method LIKE '%BONUS%'
                        AND (Method NOT LIKE '%CASHBACKBONUS%')
                        THEN Amount
                    ELSE 0
                    END) LT_Bo_No_CashB
            ,sum(CASE 
                    WHEN Method LIKE 'CASHBACKBONUS'
                        THEN Amount
                    ELSE 0
                    END) LT_CashBack
            ,sum(CASE 
                    WHEN Method LIKE '%BONUS%'
                        AND (Method NOT LIKE '%CASHBACKBONUS%')
                        THEN Amount
                    ELSE 0
                    END) + sum(CASE 
                    WHEN Method LIKE 'CASHBACKBONUS'
                        THEN Amount
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS LT_TotBonus
        FROM `Online_dailyfinance_v2`
        GROUP BY Account
        ) e ON a.Customers = e.Account
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT loyalty_points.status_name
            ,loyalty_points.cash_back_per
            ,loyalty_points.cash_back_BO_per
        FROM loyalty_points
        ) f ON a.status_name = f.status_name
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT Account
            ,sum(CASE 
                    WHEN Method LIKE 'CASHBACKBONUS'
                        THEN Amount
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS CashBack_Last30D
        FROM `Online_dailyfinance_v2`
        WHERE Online_dailyfinance_v2.DATE >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
        GROUP BY Account
        ) g ON a.Customers = g.Account
    )
ORDER BY c.LTRM DESC
```

Comment: This isn't a code translation service... If you can't use subqueries, then you'll have to rewrite to NOT use them.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your useful comment. Maybe someone could kindly give me a hint...

Comment: There is a workaround for server-side PHP handler to enable support for JOINs, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31007028/3549014)

Answer (score 0):

@Renaud, I applaud your persistence in creating this ambitious query. One thing that stands out is that you're having to do "LIKE" statements. I use a lot of "reference tables" with "TINYINT" as the key to the "text". So I may have "5" as the key to "CASHBACKBONUS" and "3" as the key to just plain "BONUS". You see how that can simply things?  I hope the script kiddies with bad attitudes don't vote down my tip/answer but whenever I've run into situations that require a query like this, I usually end up creating summary tables with the range of data that I need. It's not often, but it's occasionally needed. I'll even violate 3rd normal form (oh, the HORROR!) if it makes the coding easier. But I'm the one in control of my DB so I don't know if you can make these modifications. I've been doing DB stuff for 25+ years, so take it for what you think it's worth.

Comment: .. and yeah, I don't like un-useful and derisive "answers" either. I especially don't like RTFM because I always RTFM and manuals are often vague and ambiguous. Ex: look at the def on PDO BindValue and the one for BindParam. That one causes a boatload of questions and still, somebody's going to say "RTFM". I'll keep my opinion about those people to myself.