# datatables search not work when field is out of table in database

Tags: php, datatable, datatables, datatables-1.10

I use simple datatables with default settings and server processing.
My server side codes is like this:

```
$table = 'lead';
$primaryKey = 'id';
$colnowid = 2;
// Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
// The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the `dt`
// parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case object
// parameter names

include_once( 'jdf.php' );
include_once( 'config.php' );

$columns = array(

array(
    'db' => 'id',
    'dt' => 'id',
    'formatter' => function ( $d, $row ) {
        if(1 == 1 ){
           return  '<a href="lead-add.php?id='.$d.'">ویرایش</a> ';
        }
    }
),
array(
    'db' => 'type',
    'dt' => 'type',
    'formatter' => function ( $d, $row ) {
        global $colnowid;
        return '<a href="lead-view.php?id='.$colnowid.'">'.$d.'</a>';
    }
),
array(
    'db' => 'cat',
    'dt' => 'cat',
    'formatter' => function ( $d, $row ) {
        return $d;
    }
),
array(
    'db' => 'contact_id',
    'dt' => 'contact_id',
    'formatter' => function ( $d, $row ) {
        if ( !isset( $db ) ) {
            $db = db();
        }
        if($d != '') {
            $c = qselect("select name from contact where id = $d limit 1",$db);

            return $c['name'];
        } else { 
            return '';
        }
    }
),
// SQL server connection information
$sql_details = array(
    'user' => $dbuser,
    'pass' => $dbpass,
    'db' => $dbname,
    'host' => 'localhost'
);

require( 'ssp.class.php' );
$db = db();
echo json_encode( SSP::simple( $_POST, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns ) );die;
```

Everything works perfectly.
My search for type, cat and others work ok,
but it does not search for contact name, because I get it from another table.
So, any idea how make this work?

Comment: there is a typo in 'formatter' for contact: a `}` too much before `$return $c['name'];`

Comment: @Jeff yeah sorry but its correct in codes i edit here so you can see it easy and made mistake .. anyway you know my answer?

Comment: found my answer from here. hope its help anyone else [how add join to your datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31004884/how-to-join-two-tables-with-ssp-class-php/31007028#31007028)

Answer (score 0):

[How to join two tables with ssp.class.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31004884/how-to-join-two-tables-with-ssp-class-php/31007028#31007028)
 found my answer from here
its add join and where to your server side scripts so you can join table for search become available